How to change content of clicked button (C# WinForms Toast Notification)?
I want to change content of clicked button in C# WinForms Toast Notification.
Here are my codes:
private void ButtonAction(ToastNotification sender, object args)
{
    ToastActivatedEventArgs taeaTıklananDüğme = args as ToastActivatedEventArgs;

    switch(taeaTıklananDüğme.Arguments)
    {
        case "Gates":

            MessageBox.Show("Button has been clicked!");

            break;

    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var BildiriminOzellikleri = new ToastContentBuilder()
            //.AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
            //.AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
            .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("C:\\Users\\StackOverFlow\\Desktop\\EkranResmi_07112024105204.png")) // Bildirimin sol üst köşesinde görünecek olan logo
            .AddButton(new ToastButton("Bill", "Gates")
                .SetContent("MyButton")
            )
            .AddInlineImage(new Uri("D:\\İndirilenler\\Images\\d033c77c3960090e00c0d4aa9408ef45.jpeg")) // Yazıların altında görünecek olan resim
            .AddInputTextBox("tbGosterilecekMesajiYazmaKutusu", placeHolderContent: "Please enter a text here.")
            .AddText("Hello World!") // İlk "AddText" fonksiyonu kalın harflerle başlık yazmaya yazar
            .AddText("This is a text.") // Diğer "AddText" fonksiyonu ise başlığın altına açıklama, metin vs. yazılmasını sağlar
            .AddText("This is an another text.")
            .AddVisualChild(new AdaptiveProgressBar()
            {
                Status = new BindableString("pbProgressBarStatus"),
                Title = new BindableString("pbProgressBarTitle"),
                Value = new BindableProgressBarValue("pbProgressBarValue"),
                ValueStringOverride = new BindableString("pbProgressBarValueString")
            }
            )
            .SetToastDuration(ToastDuration.Long)
            .GetToastContent();

    var Bildirim = new ToastNotification(BildiriminOzellikleri.GetXml());

    Bildirim.Activated += ButtonAction; 

    Bildirim.Group = "NotificationGroup";
    Bildirim.Tag = "NotificationTag";

    Bildirim.Data = new NotificationData();
    Bildirim.Data.Values["pbProgressBarStatus"] = "Downloading...";
    Bildirim.Data.Values["pbProgressBarTitle"] = "StackOverFlow.rar";
    Bildirim.Data.Values["pbProgressBarValue"] = "0.1";
    Bildirim.Data.Values["pbProgressBarValueString"] = "1%";

    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("cagatay").Show(Bildirim);
}

Here is the screenshoot of my notification:
https://i.sstatic.net/pB8dCE7f.png
How can I change "MyButton" text to another thing when the button is clicked?

"Change text to another thing". Do you mean change button text to other text? Or change button text to button image? Or do you want to change the button to something else?

@HaraldCoppoolse I want to change text to another text. When click that button, just text should be changed but the notification should not be disappeared.

Is button1 just a normal windows forms button? Text is just a property of the control.
If it is, try doing:
button1.Text = "New Text";

Add that to your button1_Click event.
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "New Text";
        var BildiriminOzellikleri = new ToastContentBuilder()


No. "button1" is another button which triggers the notification. Please, check out the image. I want to change the notification button. What I mean, when I clicked "MyButton" in notification, "MyButton" text should be changed.

probably the easiest way would be to hold the button in a class variable, create it at the beginning and pass the object into the method:
ToastButton buttonToChange;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonToChange = new ToastButton("Bill", "Gates").SetContent("MyButton");

    var BildiriminOzellikleri = new ToastContentBuilder()
            .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("C:\\Users\\StackOverFlow\\Desktop\\EkranResmi_07112024105204.png")) // Bildirimin sol üst köşesinde görünecek olan logo
            .AddButton(buttonToChange)) ....

and when the button is clicked call the SetContent method again:
private void ButtonAction(ToastNotification sender, object args)
{
    buttonToChange.SetContent("new content");
}

